# Change column names in list of list of data frames using lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, eval, lapply, r-colnames

This is a follow-up to this question: [Create scatter plot with interval data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632745/create-scatter-plot-with-interval-data-in-r)

I would like to change the column names in the following data.frames, that are part of a list of lists:

```
other_list #a list of arbitrary length containing some data
myvar <- "myactualMeasurement"

lapply_output <- list()
for(i in 1:length(other_list)){
  lapply_output[[i]] <- lapply(other_list[[i]], function(item){
      out_df <- data.frame('MyItem' = item$MyItem,
                           'Measurement' = item$Measurement,
                           'Interval' = seq(floor(item$First), floor(item$Last))+ 0.5)
      return(out_df)
  })
}
```

As you can see, I'm assigning the names 'MyItem', 'Measurement' and 'Interval' to my columns. 
I would like to assign the name 'Measurement' using the variable "myvar" instead of doing it manually.
I've already tried to use

```
eval(parse(text = myvar))
```

instead of 'Measurement' in my lapply structure, but that does not seem to work.

My current workaround is a nested loop which (re-)assigns the column name:

```
for(i in 1:length(other_list)){
  for(j in 1:length(lapply_output[[i]])){
    colnames(lapply_output[[i]][[j]])[which(names(lapply_output[[i]][[j]]) == "Measurement")] <- myvarpar
  }
}
```

I'm sure, there has to be a more neat way of doing this (preferentially a oneliner in the lapply structure,
but I can't come up with a good solution.

An alternative could be (see [Using lapply to change column names of a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33567101/using-lapply-to-change-column-names-of-a-list-of-data-frames)):

```
new_col_name <- c("MyItem", myvar, "Interval")
for(i in 1:length(other_list)){
  newlist[[i]] <- lapply(lapply_output[[i]], setNames, nm = new_col_name)
}
```

But this is
1) not really doing what it should do (only the last list element is preserved)
2) is also not neat

Preferentially, I would like to use something like

```
eval(parse(text = myvar))
```

in the original structure, without having to write much more additional naming code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `lapply` loops through the input list elements hence you need not duplicate with for loop indexing.
    Also there is no need to create a dummy list prior to lapply since default output class of `lapply`
    is a `list` object

You can rename the column name in one step as below with `match` being used to compare column names

```
outputVar <- "myactualMeasurement"
inputVar <- "Measurement"

outList = lapply(other_list, function(item){

      out_df <- data.frame('MyItem' = item$MyItem,
                           'Measurement' = item$Measurement,
                           'Interval' = seq(floor(item$First), floor(item$Last))+ 0.5)

      inputvarIndex <- match(inputVar,colnames(out_df))
      colnames(out_df)[inputvarIndex] <- outputVar

      return(out_df)
  })
```

I strongly suggest to thoroughly read the documentation and examples of `?lapply` and note that `eval/parse` though seemingly convenient are vulnerable to unexpected results

Comment: Thank you very much! This does the trick, indeed. The loop was necessary as I was applying the apply function to a list of lists, i. e. to the lists nested in another list. I realize now, that i did not explain this properly.
Thanks for your help!